# Export data with custom parameters Laravel Excel

Tags: php, laravel

i'm currently using version 3.1 of https://laravel-excel.com/ I want to query data and download them into excel file but it always returns a blank sheet.

my route:

```
Route::get('/reports/excel', 'ReportController@excel');
```

My ReportsExport Controller:

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromView;


class ReportsExport implements FromView, WithEvents, ShouldAutoSize
{
    use Exportable;

    private $from, $to;

    public function __construct(String $from, String $to) {

        $this->from = $from;
        $this->to = $to;
    }

    public function view(): View
    {
        return view('reports.sample', [
            'reports' => Report::whereBetween('created_at', [$this->from, $this->to])->get()
        ]);
    }
```

download controller

```
    public function excel(Request $request) {
    $from = Carbon::parse($request->get('from'));
    $to = Carbon::parse($request->get('to'));

    return Excel::download(new ReportsExport($from, $to), 'reports.xlsx');
}
```

Can you please let me know what i'm missing here? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: you can try my solution that is very simple and better way explained if any buddy so not use view method. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62493600/laravel-excel-export-how-to-export-conditional-data/70275061#70275061

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to make it work. Here's what I did:

Exports.php

```
    class ReportsExport implements FromView, WithEvents, ShouldAutoSize
{
    use Exportable;

    protected $from, $to;

    public function __construct(String $from, String $to) {

        $this->from = $from;
        $this->to = $to;
    }

    public function view(): View
    {
        return view('reports.sample', [
            'reports' => User::find(Auth::user()->id)->reports()
                   ->whereDate('created_at', '>=', $this->from)
                   ->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $this->to)
                   ->get(),


        ]);
    }
```

my Controller

```
    public function excel(Request $request) {
    $from = Carbon::parse($request->get('from'));
    $to = Carbon::parse($request->get('to'));

    return Excel::download(new ReportsExport($from, $to), 'reports.xlsx');
}
```